# What can I do against oscillating validation accuracy in CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, validation, keras, conv-neural-network, genome

I'm training a convolutional neural network and am seeing the issue that my validation accuracy is oscillating a lot. I'm seeing some oscillating on the training accuracy too but by far not as much.

What could be possible culprints? Or is this behaviour that is too be excpected in some cases?

[Accuracy - Train&Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItqnU.png)

```
Model: "sequential_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)           (None, 58, 51, 32)        1632      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_21 (Activation)   (None, 58, 51, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPooling (None, 29, 26, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_16 (Flatten)         (None, 24128)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 32)                772128    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 773,793
Trainable params: 773,793
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would guess that your learning rate is set too high. So how big is it?

Comment: I set a very low learning rate of 0,0001 and i'm using the adam optimizer in case thats relevant

Comment: Usually a small learning rate helps, but yours is already small. Try increasing the batch_size. Also if you are using a generator to create your validation images for model.fit set shuffle=False in the generator. That way you always do validation in the same ordered sequence.